# Advice on how to create my SharePoint lists for a defect detection system

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, sharepoint-list, architecture

I want to build the following defect detection system in SharePoint. The interface will be built using Power Apps. but currently i am struggled on how to build the SharePoint lists and the relation between these lists.

[image]

For sure i will have a list to store the main section marked in red, with these fields:-

- ID
- Name
- Equipment ID
- Type
- Date / Time
- Comments

but how i can represents the other info such as Heavy Equipment,Body Damage,fluid Leaks, etc.. for example? should they be represented using separate lists or one list with a category drop-down (the drop-down will have options including; Heavy Equipment,Body Damage,fluid Leaks, etc.. )? and their sub-sections?

Comment: Are the category Y/N choices selection made only once or multiple times?

Comment: @GaneshSanap no multiple times, you can select Y >> save >>then update the value to N and so on..

Comment: Then you can save those details as well in same list where you are storing ID, Name, Type, etc. and for defect details & comments, you can create another list.

Comment: @GaneshSanap so how the list will be structured including the fields ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, I'd create an App for *Equipment* first. In the Equipment App I'd store all information related to identifying and understanding each piece of equipment.

Next, I'd create a *Equipment Defects* app with a lookup column to the existing Equipment app. I'm a heavy user of SP on-premise so am not sure about online, but my understanding is that a lookup column has to be on the same site as the app it is looking up. A lookup column is SharePoint's way of establishing relationships (one to many or many to many) between lists (tables).

Next I consider your column naming choices:

- The column "Type" I would actually name "Defect Type" in the Equipment Defects app. Type is a very generic column name. What is interesting to me, particularly given how little I know about your problem/context, is that I don't know if Defect Type is best as a choice column or a lookup column to another list for Defect Types. If there is no additional information related to Defect Types that you need to work with then a choice column is fine. However, if there is information relevant to Defect Type, such as a description of the defect type for training purposes, or choices related to Defect Type that drives workflow somewhere, then a lookup column might be best. That said, a choice field is possibly sufficient based on what I can see.
- Answering this sort of question highlights why, in my opinion, some pre-planning ahead of building SharePoint apps is so important.
- As for the other columns, it would appear that *Defect Name*, *Defect Type*, *Date - Defect Registered*, and *Defect Comments* (note the renaming I suggested) could all sit within the *Equipment Defects* app.
- I would name the Equipment lookup column to the Equipment list as *Equipment - Lookup*. It's a personal choice, but I develop SharePoint platform solutions that contain thousands of Site Columns and hundreds of Apps. I like to be able to immediately spot a lookup column, so I use the suffix of "- Lookup" when naming a lookup column.

Lookup columns also have a benefit of allowing relationship behaviour to be defined at a rudimentary level. If you're not certain about these column types I would suggest doing a little reading up on them.

Comment: thanks for the info

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to follow up @john . If you try this out and it all works it would be awesome if you could mark this as the acceptable answer.

Comment: @Carewn i am planning to open boundary on this question to get as much opinions as i can .. thanks

Comment: Of course. And if anyone provides the direction you take, updating this as answered is a great way to say thanks :)